# ValueError when accessing a Table after inserting a ROW object to list:reference field

Tags: python, database, web2py

I am getting a ValueError for the DAL query `db(db.posts.id == request.vars["post"]).select().first()`, with the following TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 204, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "E:/Programming/Python/web2py/applications/vote_up/controllers/default.py", line 109, in <module>
  File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\globals.py", line 172, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "E:/Programming/Python/web2py/applications/vote_up/controllers/default.py", line 67, in vote
    if request.vars["post"]:    var = db(db.posts.id == request.vars["post"]).select().first()
  File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 6333, in select
    return self.db._adapter.select(self.query,fields,attributes)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 1287, in select
    return self.parse(rows,self._colnames)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 1533, in parse
    colset[fieldname] = bar_decode_integer(value)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 4408, in bar_decode_integer
    return [int(x) for x in value.split('|') if x.strip()]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "<Row {'joined': datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 26, 17, 42, 26), 'password': 'SS', 'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'reputation': 0}>"
```

This happened after I changed my controller to:

```
def vote():
    '''Add a vote'''
    path_to=session.path_to
    if request.vars["post"]:    var = db(db.posts.id == request.vars["post"]).select().first()
    elif request.vars["answer"]:    var = db(db.answers.id == request.vars["answer"]).select().first()
    elif request.vars["comment"]:    var = db(db.comments.id == request.vars["comment"]).select().first()
    elif request.vars["comment_r"]:    var = db(db.comments_r.id == request.vars["comment_r"]).select().first()
    else: return None
    inc = 0
    if int(request.vars["up"])==1:
        inc=1
        if not var.v_up:    var.v_up = []
        if session.user in var.v_up:    return var.votes
        var.update_record(
            votes=var.votes+inc,
            v_up = var.v_up+[session.user]
        )
    elif int(request.vars["up"])==0:
        inc=-1
        if not var.v_dn:    var.v_dn = []
        if session.user in var.v_dn:    return var.votes
        var.update_record(
            votes=var.votes+inc,
            v_dn = var.v_dn+[session.user]
        )
    return var.votes
```

The `session.user` is a ROW object of the users table, like:

```
<Row {'joined': datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 26, 17, 42, 26), 'password': 'SS', 'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'reputation': 0}>
```

The tables are structured like:

```
db.define_table('posts', 
    db.Field('title', 'string'),
    db.Field('message', 'text'),
    db.Field('user', 'reference users'),
    db.Field('votes', 'integer', default=0),
    db.Field('v_up', 'list:reference users'),
    db.Field('v_dn', 'list:reference users'),
    db.Field('time', 'datetime', default=datetime.utcnow())
)

db.define_table('users',
    db.Field('name', 'string'),
    db.Field('password', 'password'),
    db.Field('reputation', 'integer', default=0),
    db.Field('joined', 'datetime', default=datetime.utcnow())
)
```

Am I missing something trivial again?

**UPDATE:**
Looks like the `posts` table is corrupted since I get the same ValueError even for `print db(db.posts).select()`. Could `v_up = var.v_up+[session.user]` have corrupted the table? Why? And is there someway to recover it?

**UPDATE:**
Confirmed that `v_up = var.v_up+[session.user]` is corrupting the table. What is the right way to use a `list:refernce` field?

Comment: What is request.vars["post"]? Where is it set? Have you checked it's value? Presumably it's not an integer, as it should be.

Comment: @Anthony, it looks like an integer. Printing `request.vars` gives me `<Storage {'post': '10', 'up': '1'}>`.

Comment: Do you think `v_up = var.v_up+[session.user]` could have something to do with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `list:refernce` Field in DAL is a glorified integer-list field that holds ids of rows of the referenced table.

Therefore when you insert a ROW object into that field, it causes a `ValueError` as a ROW object isn't an integer id from the table.

To fix this, replace the `session.user` ROW object with its integer-id, `session.user.id`.

Here is an example from the [Web2Py book](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#Many-to-many,-list%3a%3Ctype%3E,-and-contains):

```
>>> db.define_table('tag',Field('name'),format='%(name)s')
>>> db.define_table('product',
        Field('name'),
        Field('tags','list:reference tag'))
>>> a = db.tag.insert(name='red')
>>> b = db.tag.insert(name='green')
>>> c = db.tag.insert(name='blue')
>>> db.product.insert(name='Toy Car',tags=[a, b, c])
>>> products = db(db.product.tags.contains(b)).select()
>>> for item in products:
        print item.name, item.tags
Toy Car [1, 2, 3]
>>> for item in products:
        print item.name, db.product.tags.represent(item.tags)
Toy Car red, green, blue
```

Note that the `insert` method returns the id of the ROW inserted.

Comment: What surprises me is the fact that I didn't get a warning while inserting the ROW object...

Comment: This is a bug. The check was missing. It should not be fixed in trunk. Please next time, report bugs using the mailing list or the issue tracker and they will be fixed sooner. Anyway, thanks fo reporting this problem and sorry for the rouble.

Comment: @Massimo, thank you for the prompt response. I will try to make use of the issue tracker the next time I notice a bug.... I really wish we were more active here on StackOverflow & Programmers.SE, since it can give us better visibility and also act as a Wiki/FAQ for Web2Py :)